# Countdown animation circular - CreateJS / EaselJS / TweenJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs, tweenjs

I am quite new with createJS - I want to achieve like a countdown timer animation:

I stumbled upon this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417481/countdown-animation-with-easeljs) which have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZDEP/1/) - I want to achive something like this but I want to create an arc shape:

I tried adjusting the code and changed the point values but it only gave me a diamond one instead of a perfect curve.

Do I need to point every values to achieve a perfect circle like:

```
points = [{x: 50, y: 0}, {x: 51, y: 1}, {x:52, y: 2}, ...etc]
```

Or is there other way (maybe a function or plugin) that does this stuff? I wasn't able to find anything on their [documentation](https://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/modules/TweenJS.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in using an `arc()` graphic, along with the EaselJS "Command" approach to graphics:

1) Create a full arc

```
var s = new createjs.Shape().set({x:100,y:100});
s.strokeCmd = s.graphics.s("red")
    .ss(10,"round")
    .arc(0,0,80,0,Math.PI*2)
```

2) Store off the last "command"

```
var cmd = s.command; // This will be the arc command
```

3) Set the command `endAngle` to 0. You can do this in the arc() method too

```
cmd.endAngle = 0;
```

4) In your animation, increment the `endAngle` over time. In this example I normalize 100 to mean 100% of the radius (`Math.PI*2`)

```
var index = 0;
function tick(event) {
  index += 1; // Fake Percent
  cmd.endAngle = index/100 * Math.PI*2;
  stage.update(event);
}
```

Here is a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/pgeut9cr/

If instead you just want to animate the circle over a fixed period, you can tween the `endAngle` value. Here is an example using TweenJS: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/pgeut9cr/2/

```
createjs.Tween.get(cmd)
    .to({endAngle:Math.PI*2}, 2000, createjs.Ease.quadInOut);
```

Cheers,

Comment: Nice! but how can I add "duration" on this thing?

Comment: You can set the `endAngle` any way you want. I updated my answer with an animated example using TweenJS, which animates it over 2s.

Comment: Thank you, hmmm another question (if ok) what If instead of having a red circle forming a circle, is it possible a red circle disappearing? Like an inverse or something? (Btw this edgeangle thing, I never heard of it, thank you!)

Comment: The `endAngle` is just a property of the `arc()` command: https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Arc.html -- You can animate it from `Math.PI*2` to `0` to make it disappear.