# How do you animate a line using EaselJS and TweenJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs, tween.js

My goal is to have a line ***animate*** from point A to point B using the Tween function.

The drawing library I am using is [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs) and for Tweening I am using [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs).

Is this possible using the moveTo function to ***animate*** a straight line from point A to point B?

---

My current setup is as follows:

```
var line = new createjs.Shape();
line.beginStroke('cyan');
line.setStrokeStyle(3);
line.moveTo(100, 100);
```

My goal is to animate this path from x100 y100 to x0 y0.

---

#### Animation Example:

I have tried this using the following and nothing happens:

```
var line = new createjs.Shape();
line.beginStroke('cyan');
line.setStrokeStyle(3);
line.moveTo(100, 100);
createjs.Tween.get(line).to({x: 0, y: 0}, 1000, createjs.Ease.sineInOut);
```

> Nothing happens.

---

#### Draw Example:

However if I use this I get the line as expected but it is not animated:

```
var line = new createjs.Shape();
line.beginStroke('cyan');
line.setStrokeStyle(3);
line.moveTo(100, 100);
line.lineTo(0, 0);
```

> This draws a line as expected.

---

Is there some way to use the lineTo method with the tweening method I am missing? I have checked the documentation of both Easel and TweenJS and can't find an example or any clear instructions on how to do this or if this is not possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid you may need to add a [mcve] to your question to troubleshoot correctly, there is not enough code to find out why what you are doing does not work

Comment: @ochi I have updated the example with a more comprehensive starting point this should help you understand what I'm trying to achieve. Please let me know if you feel something is missing.

Comment: Looking at the API (http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_lineTo) it indicates that before you use `lineTo(x,y)` you must call `moveTo(x,y)` - so it seems that move to is equivalent to lifting the pencil and moving the cursor to the given coords and then line to lowers the pencil and moves it to the given coords (effectively drawing the line as the pencil is now down, touching the canvas)

Comment: Hey @ochi Thanks for the update. Yes I have read the documentation and I understand that moveTo is needed before changing the position of the line. I have updated the examples again to show each case in full so it is more clear. I am in fact using moveTo in both examples to place the starting position of the line then in each case am using a different method to move the line. In the first I am attempting to use the Tween function to animate it ( and failing ) and in the second I am using the lineTo method and succeeding with no animation.

Comment: I see, sorry it was not clear to me from the start

Comment: @ochi That's ok thank you for helping me improve the quality of my question.

Comment: I think this answer will get you there http://stackoverflow.com/a/32905293/600486

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use a Graphics command. The `.command` property returns the last created graphics command, which you can then manipulate with a tween:

```
var cmd = line.graphics.lineTo(100,100).command;
createjs.Tween.get(cmd).to({x:0}, 1000);
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gskinner/17Lk8a9s/1/

Comment: How do you go about doing this with a diagonal line?

Comment: Just tween the y value as well.

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thpbr1vt/3/

Attention! Performance.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
var vpoint = new createjs.Point( 100, 100);

var line = new createjs.Graphics();
line.beginStroke( 'cyan' );
line.moveTo( vpoint.x, vpoint.y );
var s = new createjs.Shape(line);
stage.addChild(s);

createjs.Tween.get(vpoint).to({x: 0, y: 0}, 1000, createjs.Ease.sineInOut);

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
  function tick() { 
  line.lineTo( vpoint.x, vpoint.y );
  stage.update();
}
```

Comment: How do you go about creating a diagonal line?

Comment: My example is a diagonal line !?